# this.style.backgroundColor don't work in IE7/8

Tags: javascript, background-color, onmousemove, attachevent

my code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Demo</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <style type="text/css">
        p{
            border:1px solid #CCC;
            margin:5px;
            padding:5px;
        }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.onload = changeColor;
        function changeColor() {
            for(var i =0; i < document.getElementById("main").getElementsByTagName("p").length; i++) {
                var obj = document.getElementById("main").getElementsByTagName("p")[i];
                if (window.addEventListener) {
                    obj.addEventListener('mousemove', function () {
                        this.style.backgroundColor ="#EEE";
                    }, false);
                    obj.addEventListener('mouseout', function () {
                        this.style.backgroundColor ="#FFF";
                    }, false);
                } else if (window.attachEvent) {
                    //for ie
                    obj.attachEvent('onmousemove', function () {
                        this.style.backgroundColor ="#EEE";
                    });
                    obj.attachEvent('onmouseout', function () {
                        this.style.backgroundColor ="#FFF";
                    });
                }
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <p>1</p>
        <div id="main">
            <p>2.1</p>
            <p>2.2</p>
            <p>2.3</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

it work well in Chrome、FireFox and ie9,but can't work in IE7/8

the error message is:Unable to set the property value of the "backgroundColor": the object is null or undefined

what's rong with me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `attachEvent` in IE, `this` is set to the `window` object, not to the object that the event happened on.

In IE, the global variable `window.event.srcElement` will contain the target object for the event.

You could code a work-around like this to make all the event handlers work the same:

```
function hookEvent(event, obj, fn) {
    if (obj.addEventListener) {
        obj.addEventListener(event, fn, false);
    } else {
        obj.attachEvent("on" + event, function() {return(fn.call(obj, window.event));});
    }
}
```

This will make it so that `this` is set to the source object of the event and that the argument to the event handler is the event object.

Comment: Added a helper function that makes `attachEvent()` work like `addEventListener()`.

Answer (score 0):

`this` is not bound to the source element in IE's `attachEvent`.

Use `event.srcElement` instead.

Also note that the `event` global object property and its `srcElement` property are IE-specific as well.