# `this` object does not return an object

Tags: javascript, object, this

I have two codes, one to work on modern browsers like(IE9+, ff, Ch, etc), and another to work with old browsers like (ie6,7).

**For modern browsers.**

```
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('p');
for (i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    elements[i].addEventListener('click', function () {
        this.style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';
    });
}
```

**For old browsers (ex: ie6,7)**

```
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('p');
for (i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    elements[i].attachEvent('onclick', function () {
        this.style.backgroundColor = 'yellow'; // here is the problem in `this` object.
    });
}
```

The first code work fine, because `this` return an object correctly.

But the second code does not work fine, because `this` does not return an object correctly.
The error message that appear in `IE 6,7`: `Unable to set value of the property 'backgroundColor': object is null or undefined`

**What is the problem ?, and how can I solve it ?**

Comment: It actually looks like `this.style` might be undefined.

Comment: Is there a reason you're not just using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/)? It irons out these browser differences for you, so you can focus on the interesting stuff.

Comment: @Joe White: I think if I use `jquery`, this is not the solution, but escape from solving the problem, and I did not want to do that.

Comment: Honestly, in this day and age, I wouldn't consider IE6/7 compatibility to be a problem worth spending your time learning how to solve.

Comment: Try `this.style['background-color'] = 'yellow' `

Comment: @Dom: Unfortunately, the problem still exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this` does not point to the current target element in IE versions < 9

Refer [this.style.backgroundColor don't work in IE7/8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9355821/this-style-backgroundcolor-dont-work-in-ie7-8)

Comment: Thank you, your answer Contributed in solving the problem.

Answer (score 0):

**The solution of the problem on** `IE 6,7` .

```
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('p');
for (i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    elements[i].attachEvent('onclick', function () {
        window.event.srcElement.style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';
    });
}
```

Also another way.

```
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('p');
var event = window.event;
for (i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    elements[i].attachEvent('onclick', function (event) {
        event.srcElement.style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';
    });
}
```

Comment: Are you sure this works when the clicked element is some child of the surrounding `<p>` element?

Comment: Yes, I have tested it on `IE6` and `IE7` and works fine when clicked on the parent element, and also children that belong to this parent.   
and for that reason, I posted the code in order utilized to everyone .